# Spring JPA how can I retrieve join table with a given property?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, join, many-to-many

I am working on a Spring project and I am using JPA to access database. I have two tables that have `@ManyToMany` property. And one other table (join table) that keeps the foreign keys of those two tables. I need to retrieve the join table with a given property of one of the tables. I tried to use JPA methods and queries but I couldn't find a solution.

I have an abstract class called `Course`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID courseId;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "course_code", nullable = false)
    private String courseCode;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false)
    private String courseName;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ects", nullable = false)
    private Double ects; 

    public Course(
        @JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
        @JsonProperty("courseCode") String courseCode,
        @JsonProperty("courseName") String courseName,
        @JsonProperty("ects") Double ects) {

        this.courseId = id;
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.ects = ects;
    }
}
```

I have two database model classes that extends `Course`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "uni_course")
public class UniCourse extends Course {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "department", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "approved_courses", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uni_course_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "host_course_id"))
    private Set<HostCourse> approvedCourses;
    
    public UniCourse(
        @JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
        @JsonProperty("courseCode") String courseCode,
        @JsonProperty("courseName") String courseName,
        @JsonProperty("ects") Double ects,
        @JsonProperty("department") Department department) {

        super(id, courseCode, courseName, ects);
        this.department = department;
        this.bilkentCredit = bilkentCredit;
    }
}
```

and,

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "host_course")
public class HostCourse extends Course {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "syllabus", nullable = false)
    private String syllabus;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "web_page", nullable = true)
    private String webPage;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "university_id", nullable = false)
    private UUID universityId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "approvedCourses")
    private Set<UniCourse> uniCourses;
    
    public HostCourse(
        @JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
        @JsonProperty("courseCode") String courseCode,
        @JsonProperty("courseName") String courseName,
        @JsonProperty("ects") Double ects,
        @JsonProperty("syllabus") String syllabus,
        @JsonProperty("webPage") String webPage,
        @JsonProperty("universityId") UUID universityId) {
        
        super(id, courseCode, courseName, ects);
        this.syllabus = syllabus;
        this.webPage = webPage;
        this.universityId = universityId;
        this.courseApproval = courseApproval;
    }
}
```

I want to get `approvedCourses` using `universityId` of `HostCourse`. How can I achieve this?

I tried using the `findByApprovedCoursesUniversityId(UUID universityId)` method and it returned the following:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "courseCode": "CS315",
            "courseName": "Programming Languages",
            "ects": 5.0,
            "department": "CS",
            "courseId": "8a890716-aaf1-40bb-81b2-e0a638b878dd",
            "approvedCourses": []
        }
    ]
    "timestamp": "2022.12.15 21.48.32",
    "status": "OK"
}
```

I also want to get approved courses but it returns an empty array.

Comment: It isn't clear what you really want - approved_courses is just a key/value table. Are you asking how to get HostCourse referenced by a UniCourse? We can't know what your findByApprovedCoursesUniversityId is unless you show the definition. Is the issue that your JSON data isn't including the approvedCourses list, or is it you do not know how to write the Query to fetch particular data?

Comment: I want to get all UniCourse and their respected approvedCourses (HostCourse) with a given universityId. 

This the definition of the method:
`public interface IUniCourseRepository extends JpaRepository<UniCourse, UUID> {
    List<Object> findByApprovedCoursesUniversityId(UUID universityId);
}`

I don't know how to write a query that fetches UniCourse and HostCourse using universityId.

Comment: Are you able to write the query to get the instances you want, or is it a problem with the JSON data being sent back. Spring combines far too much into 'repositories', so it isn't clear from this which part you are really asking for. You've a bunch of JSON annotations on data, but have excluded the approvedCourses and uniCourses properties, so I wonder if they are ever sent back with your JSON data or how it is sending []. Otherwise, just using a List<HostCourse> findByUniversityId(UUID universityId); should work for you, as the returned HostCourses should reference the uniCourses set you want